# Identify when an SSRS Schedule was removed from Report Manager and by whom

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to identify when a SSRS Report Schedule was removed and by whom?

Thanks,

Comment: +1 for a tough question. I'd post an answer of "No, you can't" but the army of minus one'ers would kill me. My best guess is "no, you can't" - see following link --> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/60206bdc-24be-40c9-85bd-357a4d88728d/ssrs-2008-audit-security-changes-to-report-manager-permissions?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I don't think it's logged inherently. Best bet might be to create a trigger on the relevant ReportServer tables, saving the info on updates/deletes to a auditing table.

Answer (score 0):

create a sql server audit on the relevant ReportServer database tables.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280525(v=sql.105).aspx